# Sporadically UnsatisfiedLinkError with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm looking for clues why my Android app sporadically throws an UnsatisfiedlinkError exception on a specific ndk call:

I have an Android app that loads one native library through ndk.

The native library is written in C++ and uses STL (in my makefile I have set APP_STL := stlport_static). No other libraries are used or required. The native library has about 300 native methods for about 20 java classes.

All works fine, most of the time. But every now and then my users get an UnsatisfiedLinkError exception. The exception is always triggered at the same spot with the same native function call, but strangely enough it is not even the first call to a native function, not even the first call to that specific native function.

Any clue would be welcome why one specific native call could fails. Can ndk easily be corrupted? How do you debug for such a problem?

Simple test programs with the same call work just fine. Nevertheless here's some parts of the source code:

Here's the problem ndk function in Java:

```
public class Server {
...
    static private native long longObserveError( );
...
}
```

Here's the header file:
    extern "C" {
    ...

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_be_gentgo_tetsuki_Server_longObserveError
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
...
}
```

And here's the implementation:

```
IGSProtocol *server = 0; // initialized later...

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_be_gentgo_tetsuki_Server_longObserveError
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass)
 {
   Messenger &mess = server->ObserveError( );
   return (long)(&mess);
 }
```

Comment: Not sure 
but try allocating memory for your pointer

Answer (score 2):

What is the name of your library file?  I came across another SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024816) where the guy had a library name that was conflicting with a system library that was only present on some devices.  Renaming his library fixed the problem.