# UnsatisfiedLinkExeption when installed from Google Play

Tags: java, android, google-play, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I've published my app using a library (FfmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) on Google Play Store. The library is compiled for `armabi-v7`, `armabi`, `x86` and `mips`. The signed apk was tested before publishing and everything worked well. 
But when I now install the app from Google Play, it unexpectedly gives me an `UnsatisfiedLinkExeption` of the library.
What can I do?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818058/android-ndk-unsatisfiedlinkerror-a-surprising-reason

Comment: Sadly it also does not work when installing it first.

Comment: Is the size of the downloaded APK the same as the signed version?